# filmic blender issues

Tags: rendering

I was trying to download the filmic blender plug in but I do not believe that I successfully integrated it with 2.79. I do not have the RGB EOTF option as you can see in the rendered view section under colour management.  [image]

Comment: It is not a plugin. Please follow the directions from the [github page](https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender). Download the files, go to the directory where blender is installed and substitute the color management folder with the one you downloaded

Comment: Isn't it actually included as an add-on in 2.79?

Answer (score 2):

In your version of Blender [2.79], [filmic is already integrated](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Cycles) into Blender.

You can see in the active dropdown menu: **View Transform > Filmic**

It doesn't need to be manually installed anymore.

Nevertheless, you can still use the old configuration, but there is no need to do so.

> For more details see the original Filmic Blender Configuration, which can still be used as an alternative to the builtin Blender configuration.

Comment: The filmic blender version included blender 2.79 does not use the sRGB EOTF view transform, and there are a few other things that are implemented differently from the original github version.

Comment: @cegaton, Right, should I remove this answer? Since the actual answer is found at [How?](https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender#how)

Comment: @cegaton Is there a quality drop at all between the github version and the already implemented one in 2.79?  What are the major differences from a practical standpoint?

Comment: @TylerDahl https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/107372/30849