# Filmic color management not installing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, filmic-blender

getting this error when trying to install filmic color management:

[image]

I looked inside my color management folder and saw there was filmic files all over:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmD9A.png)

[image]

Any way it is downloaded but maybe not displaying or something?
I followed this tutorial precisely: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nYGJI0r2-0

Comment: Where did you download filmic from? Filmic is not an addon in the traditional sense, it replaces the colormanagement folder entirely. See the [github](https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender) page if you have not yet, and follow the instructions there *precisely*.

Comment: Isn't Filmic part of default Blender now?  IIRC, you don't have to install anything, just enable it in Color Management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender 2.79 is bundled with Filmic already. Just download that and use it, no need to install anything else.

The error is caused by Blender trying to write to a write-protected directory. You can solve that by changing the directory permissions or running Blender as admin, but you should probably do neither and just use 2.79.

Comment: So that's good to know because I realy like that feature and exlpored it some time ago. Thanks!

Comment: A few reasons: [Are there significant differences between filmic shipped with blender and its development version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107372/are-there-significant-differences-between-filmic-shipped-with-blender-and-its-de)