# How to install Filmic Blender?

Tags: installation, filmic-blender

I am new to Blender. Today I caught a treatise by Andrew Price on photo realism, and he suggested installing Filmic Blender but when I went into my Blender Folder I found no other folders such as the "colormanagement" you refer to in your post.

How to install Filmic?

Comment: I believe as of version 2.79 Filmic color management is already built into Blender, you just need to use it in the settings.

Comment: You can read all about filmic [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46940/31447). There is a version built-in as of blender 2.79b *but* consider that there are [differences to the original repository](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107372/are-there-significant-differences-between-filmic-shipped-with-blender-and-its-de).

Comment: /blender/bin/[VERSION]/datafiles/colormanagement (C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender[VERSION]\datafiles\colormanagement on windows)

Comment: You could refer this https://youtu.be/m9AT7H4GGrA at **12:29**.

Answer (score 1):

As Rix said, just download Blender 2.79, it has Filmic built in.