# Is filmic blender already included in Blender 2.8?

Tags: filmic-blender

Is filmic blender already included in Blender 2.8?  I'm referring to the filmic blender from sobotka.github.io/filmic-blender/.  The blender guru had a tutorial on lighting.  In which, he mentioned downloading this for blender 2.79.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes but still would go to github myself. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107372/are-there-significant-differences-between-filmic-shipped-with-blender-and-its-de

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Blender includes the [view transforms](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#render) *Filmic* and *Filmic Log*. The implementation in Blender was originally created by Troy Sobotka, who independently continues the development in his [own repository](https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender).

[image: Color Management]

Comment: Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: @YanIronmonger If the answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can find the view transform option under render properties/color management. Here it is already set to filmic.