# Filmic Blender and filmic Log

Tags: filmic-blender

i watched the blender guru filmic blender video and then i tried to play with color management , but i found that the filmic log color space is already there in the blender , so is this the same color space as he is talking about in the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9AT7H4GGrA , although u tried to install the space from github but failed

Comment: If you keep watching the tutorial, Andrew did mention that it is included in newer Blender and no need for the addon.

Comment: write that as an awnsere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep watching the tutorial, Andrew did mention that it is included in newer Blender and no need for the addon.

And also in the video description:

> The Filmic addon is no longer required and will actually potentially cause some compatibility issues with other addons.
> Filmic is now included with Blender by default and can be configured via the color management panel.

[image]

Comment: [Are there significant differences between Filmic shipped with Blender and its development version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/107372/31447)

Comment: @brockmann Didn't know that information. Should this question mark as duplicate?