# How to fix lighting artifacts due to filmic blender?

Tags: shaders, lighting, color-management, filmic-blender

Currently I am using blender 2.83.10. After watching [Blender Gurus tutorial on photorealism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9AT7H4GGrA&t=978s) I switched the default datafiles\colormanagement folder with Filmic-blender that I got from github. Since then few of the object in the scene dont have a smooth light to shadow transition and are showing lighting artifacts. In order to fix this issue I have tried the following:

1. Swapping back to original colormanagement folder.
2. opening the scene in blender 2.91.

Still facing the issue.

The attached are the screenshot of the problem and my current color management setting.
[image: problem]

[image: Settings]

Comment: What is the issue? It is not clear.

Comment: @susu Edited the original post a bit, check if it helps.

Comment: You changed the transform but not the lighting is that correct? Filmic from github is not the same as filmic in standard blender. Please read around here on filmic and how it works, use false color to gauge your lighting, and use the color balance node set to *offset power slope* to work on the final image.

Comment: Some helpful questions, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107372/are-there-significant-differences-between-filmic-shipped-with-blender-and-its-de https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55231/what-is-the-the-asc-cdl-node https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55859/using-the-false-color-look-in-combination-with-the-cdl-node-to-work-on-wide-dyna